# How to solve this recursion T(n) = 5T(n/2) + n^2 lg n using master's theorem?

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

Problem 1.8 in MIT handout is the above recursion
http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring02/handouts/mastersol.pdf

Solution in the handout is T(n) = Θ(n^lg5) (case 1). I don't get any epsilon value which will satisfy the condition for case 1. Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: Can you provide the version of master theorem you have?

Comment: @Mai I am following the master theorem version in this link. Please refer page 52  http://www.ime.usp.br/~geiser/courses/MAC5711%20-%20An%C3%A1lise%20de%20Algoritmos/Introduction%20to%20Algorithms%20(Instructor's%20Manual).pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lg n is O(n^0.1) (any positive real will do instead of 0.1), so n^2 lg n is O(n^2.1), which suffices since 2.1 < lg 5 (2.32...).

Comment: I took n=256 and lg n = O(n^0.1) fails. lg 256 -> 8 and 256 ^ 0.1 = 1.74.

Comment: @Hemanthkumar With big-O, it suffices if that inequality only holds for n > 2^100 (which it most certainly does).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @David